# efficiency of reversible carnot engine

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

here two reversible engines working between same temperature(1-a-b-c-a ;2- a-b-c-d-a),by carnot's theorem they will have same efficiency, but i could not understand from figures as the out put (closed area) of 1st one is less than second one , but they took same energy from the heat source, so where i am misleading? please explain from the diagram

Answer (score 2):

Only 1 adiabat passes through each point of a PV diagram, so the return curve $CA$ in the 1st diagram cannot be an adiabat. This means that there is some heat transfer occurring along this  curve while the temperature varies. Therefore either the engine's working substance is in contact with a reservoir with a finite temperature difference, in which case the process is not quasi-static and the heat engine is not reversible, or the working substance is in contact with a series of reservoirs at different temperatures along the curve, in which case it is not a heat engine operating between reservoirs at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$.

In the first case the engine is less efficient than than the Carnot engine as a reversible heat engine has the highest possible efficiency and in the second case you effectively have a series of reversible heat engines between reservoirs with a temperature ratio less than $T_2/T_1$, which is again less efficient.

Comment: ya I understand,  actually I want to know that,is it not possible to make a reversible engine without carnot cycle. any reversible engine with more or less four process? with any other sequence?

Comment: I principle I don't see any reason why you couldn't devise a reversible heat engine with fewer than four processes. Often you want to use heat engines as a model for processes which happen continuously and don't break down into distinct stages at all. The requirement that the process be reversible, however, puts constraints on the path the process can take. Ultimately these constraints boil down to ensuring that the total entropy of the engine plus its surroundings does not change for reversible processes.

Comment: pls if possible pls make a sketch  of a reversibl engine's  P-V diagram other than carnot's cycle following carnot's theorem  and let me show,  it must be works between only 2 temperature

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simpler one that can be sketched on a PV diagram. Any heat transfer must occur at either T1 or T2, i.e. be along an isotherm. Any other change in the system must have no heat transfer, i.e. be along an adiabat. I can't think a way to do something fundamentally different from the Carnot cycle without adding more variables or more reservoirs.